# Join Embedded Id Columns with Hibernate in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

In my maintenance entity class i have only chartDetailId like database. I want to fetch chart Entity via this chartDetailId in maintenance  entity class . But in maintenance table i just have chartDetailId I don't have chartId to join chart table.I want to join chart table but I could'nt join this table . How can i join chart table from maintenance table ?

In my hibernate code I tried to join ChartDetail table via chartDetailId in Maintenance table like below but it didn't worked.

```
select t from Maintenance as m
left join fetch m.chartDetailId as chartDetail
```

**In Maintenance class** (I tried OneToOne with join columns but without chart property in maintenance table i cannot join chart column ) :

```
@Entity
class Maintenance{

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "CHART_DETAIL_ID.CHART_ID", referencedColumnName = "CHART__ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "CHART_DETAIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "CHART_DETAIL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private ChartDetail chartDetail ;

    other properties and equals and hascode methods..
}
```

**In my chartDetail class I have composite id with embeddedId like below**

```
@Entity
class ChartDetail{

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChartDetailPK id = new ChartDetailPK()
}
```

**ChartDetailPK class :**

```
@Embeddable
class ChartDetailPK implements Serializable{
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHART_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")
    Chart chart;

    @Column(name = "CHART_DETAIL_ID",nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "CHART_DET_SEQ")
    Long chartDetailId;

equals and hascode methods...
}
```

**Chart class:**

```
@Entity
class Chart{
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "CHART_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID",nullable = false)
    private Long id;

other properties and equals and hascode methods..
}
```

**My Maintenance Table In Database :**

chartDetailId,
..

**My Chart Table In Database :**

ChartId
...

**My Chart Detail Table In Database :**

chartDetailId,
chartId
..

Can't we join without using join columns I mean with one join column in this case just chartDetail not chart  maybe ? Can we do this ?

**PROJECT ENVIRONMENTS :**

1. HİBERNATE 4.0.1.Final
2. JAVA 6